# Setting the privacy of a video uploaded to facebook using the koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, koala

I am trying to post a video to facebook using koala. everything seems to work except that I am unable to set the privacy settings of the video. my code is
`result = fb_graph.put_video(video_path, {:title => self.title, :description =>     self.description, :privacy => '{"value": "CUSTOM", "friends": "SELF"}'})`

How can I set the privacy correctly?